# Cannot find black theme in Microsoft Office 2016. Can't enable dark mode

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am using Microsoft Office 2016. The 2016 office version I have on my desktop PC has been activated.

I would like to enable dark mode. When I search on Google, the instructions say enable `Black` Office Theme under Account options. However, I cannot find `Black` theme. Only Colorful, Dark Gray, White themes are available on my PC. How can I get Black Theme to be available on Office 2016?